# Configuração hibernate!

Tags: java, sql, jsf, hibernate

Olá estou com uma dificuldade em relação a uma configuração do hibernate `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` eu acredito q estou fazendo tudo certo para achar o caminho do sql, estou utilizando a mesma para inserir alguns dados em umas tabelas assim que o banco é criado

```
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/usuarios" ></property>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.shutdown" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="/resources/sql/init.sql"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
```

esse init.sql fica na pasta web/WEB-INF/resources/sql/init.sql (padrão maven)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui fazer da seguinte maneira: coloquei o persistence `src/main/resource/META-INF/sql/dados.sql` e as property ficaram da seguinte maneira

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="META-INF/sql/dados.sql"/>
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

o persistence ficou na pasta resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o correto seria alterar o diretório dos seus scripts para `src/META-INF/sql/init.sql` ficaria no mesmo nível do seu arquivo **persistence.xml**

No seu arquivo persistence.xml ficaria com essas configurações:

```
....
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata" />
<property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/sql/init.sql"/>
....
```